# Absolute build patch in exeptions on self-contained .Net Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, self-contained

I published and deployed self-contained .Net Core 1.1 application to Debian 8. When i runing my application and throw unhandled exception i see (by `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()`) my local absolute build path from dev stage

```
XXX in C:\Users\YYY\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\Controllers\HomeController.cs
```

Application running well but how can i make it relative or absolute to current machine? I don't want any references from dev stage on production